# Reference on variance of maximum of Gaussians

Tags: pr.probability

I have been told that if $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ is a centered Gaussian vector, then
$$
    \mathrm {Var} (\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} X_k )
    \leq \max_{1 \leq k \leq n}  \mathrm {Var} (X_k) .
$$
What is a reference for this result with a proof?

Comment: I presume the $X_i$'s are independent? for the record, when $n=2$ the variance of the maximum equals the sum of the variances times $(1-1/\pi)/2$ and your inequality holds.

Comment: Marcus, I believe the Lipschitz constant would be the operator norm of L here, instead of the maximum of the diagonal elements of L

Comment: @Rob, if the entries are iid, the variance of the max can be much smaller than the max of the variance, see Proposition 4.7 in https://projecteuclid.org/journals/electronic-communications-in-probability/volume-17/issue-none/Concentration-inequalities-for-order-statistics/10.1214/ECP.v17-2210.full

Comment: Thank you, but I actually care about constant 1 (for a general Gaussian vector): if what I heard is correct, this is a supernice and striking result!

Comment: With constant 4 this follows from the Borell-TIS inequality

Answer (score 2):

A standard proof, part of the folklore, is the following. Start from the Poincaré inequality for the
canonical Gaussian measure $\gamma$ on $\mathbb {R}^n$,
$$
    \mathrm {Var}_\gamma (F) \leq \int_{\mathbb {R}^n} \| \nabla F\|_2^2 \, d\gamma
$$
for every smooth $F : \mathbb {R}^n \to \mathbb {R}$. After a linear change of variables,
$$
    \mathrm {Var} (F(X)) \leq  E \big ( \langle C \nabla F, \nabla F \rangle (X)\big)
$$
where $C$ is the covariance matrix of the Gaussian vector $X = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$.
Apply then this inequality to (a smooth approximation of) $F(x) = \max_{1 \leq k \leq n} x_k$, $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb {R}^n$.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!